# How to reduce Table Font Size in RDLC Report?

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am using Winform, C#, Mysql in Project.

In that i add one RDLC report. and created table. its have more then 35 columns. So table very large. I make strech in the table. But till the table long. So i deside to reduce the Font Size of the Table.

So that i change the Tablex Font 10pt to 5pt. But Nothing Change.

[image]

When I take a PDF Format. It Split Two page. Is not A good Format Report Na.

So Pls Help me....

Comment: i change the report properties to Landscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font of the table doesn't appear to change cells that already exist. Click the grey bar on the left of the table to select an entire row (for example, the one with three lines changes the detail row) and change the font there. All the cells in that row will have their font changed.